# Solve ODE with non-negative and maximization constraints

Tags: optimization, ode, constrained-optimization

My task is to solve $$\eta_k\frac{d^2C_k}{dz}(z)=-e_k, k = 1,2,3$$

$$C_k\ge0$$

$$C_1(0)=0, C_2(0)=A, C_3(0)=0$$
$$C_1(L)=B, \frac{dC_2}{dz}(L)=0, \frac{dC_3}{dz}(L)=0$$
with $$e_1 = -\beta_1-\beta_3$$
$$e_2=-\beta_1-\beta_2$$
$$e_3=\beta_2-\beta_3$$

satisfying the constraints $$-e_k\le \frac{\eta_kC_k}{K_k+C_k}$$ where $\eta_k, K_k$ are some constants, where $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3$ are such that $$\max 19\beta_1+0.5\beta_2+16\beta_3$$ is obtained.

> I try to solve it by iterations, treating the ODE and the optimization as two separated steps. For every iteration,
>
> 1. First solve the ode to get some $C_k$;
> 2. then I fix $C_k$ and solve the linear programming to get $e_k$.

I repeat the above two steps to iteratively get next $C_k$, "$e_k$", and so on. **My main problem** is I do not know how to properly guarantee $C_k\ge0$ when solving the ODE. **Any reference to papers or software packages that enforce such constraint** is very much appreciated!

Without being able to guarantee that constraint, the above iterative process does not seem to converge and give weird oscillations.

Comment: What is a "maximisation constraint"?

Comment: Try flipping it around and solve it as an ODE-coinstrained maximization problem which includes $C_k \ge 0$ among the constraints.